# How do I select a checkbox in a list with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this Code from a tutorial on YouTube on how to handle lists, now I want to add a CheckBox as the trailing Widget so I can use a checkbox to select the item I want instead of just tapping on the name of the drink, which sends the product into the CheckoutScreen (Cart). I want to send the name of the drink by checking a CheckBox.

Please Help me I am new to Programming

This is the Main method

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/src/material/colors.dart';
import 'CheckoutScreen.dart';
import 'ProductModel.dart';
import 'ProductScreen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: CartApp());
  }
}
```

```
class CartApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartAppState createState() => _CartAppState();
}

class _CartAppState extends State<CartApp> {
  List<ProductModel> cart = [];
  int sum = 0;

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("The Bar"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[100],
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: "Products",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Checkout",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ProductScreen((selectedProduct) {
              setState(() {
                cart.add(selectedProduct); //update
                sum = 0;
                cart.forEach((item) {
                  sum = sum + item.price;
                });
              });
            }),
            CheckoutScreen(cart, sum),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The ProductScreen class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_radio_button_group/flutter_radio_button_group.dart';

import 'ProductModel.dart';

class ProductScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueSetter<ProductModel> _valueSetter;

  ProductScreen(this._valueSetter);

  List<ProductModel> products = [
    ProductModel("GIN COCKTAILS", "Clover Club", 65),
    ProductModel("Beer", "Heineken NRB", 29),
    ProductModel("Vodka", "Ciroc", 35),
    ProductModel("Vodka", "Cruz Vodka", 30),
    ProductModel("COGNAC", "Hennesy", 40),
    ProductModel("Tequilla", "El Jimador", 30),
    ProductModel("Non-Alcoholic", "Soft-Drink", 20),
    ProductModel("WHISK[E]Y", "Johnie Walker Red", 25),
  ];

  bool checkBoxValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              products[index].category,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.redAccent[100],
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              "${products[index].name} " +
                  "\t" +
                  "\t" +
                  "\t" +
                  "\t" +
                  "\R${products[index].price}",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            ),
            trailing: Checkbox(
                value: checkBoxValue,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  checkBoxValue = value;
                }),
            onTap: () {
              _valueSetter(products[index]);
            },
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider();
        },
        itemCount: products.length);
  }
}
```

The CheckoutScreen Class (Cart)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class CheckoutScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final cart;
  final sum;

  CheckoutScreen(this.cart, this.sum);
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(cart[index].category),
              subtitle: Text(cart[index].name),
              trailing: Text(
                "\R${cart[index].price}",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Divider();
          },
          itemCount: cart.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
        ),
        Divider(),
        Text("Total : \R$sum"),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Confirm Order"),
          onPressed: () {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "Order Confirmed",
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The ProductModel Class where I declared my list

```
class ProductModel {
  String category;
  String name;
  int price;


  ProductModel(String category, String name, int price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.category = category;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`CheckboxListTile`** instead of `ListTile` so you can easily select by clicking title or it's name, See below code for more:-

```html
                List
                  .map((item) => CheckboxListTile(
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, // it will indicate left side checkbox.
                        title: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: AutoSizeText(
                                    other widgets.....
```

Comment: Thank You let me try that out